# web2py FPDF subclass and super()

Tags: python-2.7, subclass, web2py, fpdf, super

Python 2.7

Yet another new style class question... but not.

I have read the other questions and I seem to be getting the opposite result, but that is probably my ignorance.

```
class t1(object):
     pass

c1 = t1()
print type(c1) # <class '__main__.t1'> within web2py <class '__restricted__.t1>

class t2():
    pass

c2 = t2()
print type(c2) # <type 'instance'>
```

ok. great I don't have to pass 'object' to get new style classes (or have I missed something).
So when I subclass something which should be a new style class (ie has 'object' passed in declaration) I am getting a class object which I can't fix by passing 'object' in my class declaration.

now to my specific situation:
I am subclassing FPDF which is declared class FPDF(object) and trying to use the super function in my declaration.

```
class MyFPDF(FPDF):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super(MyFPDF, self).__init__()
        self.res = data['res'] # reseller info
        self.cust = data['customer'] # customer info

    super(MyFPDF, self).__init__()
TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not function
```

I can't find a reference to this specific error anywhere.

**Update**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from fpdf import FPDF, HTMLMixin
import datetime
import os
import codecs
import PIL

@auth.requires_login()
class MyFPDF(FPDF, HTMLMixin):

    # cutoff to start the next page. Not using auto page break.
    cutoff = 275
    footerLineheight = 3
    footerFontSize = 6.5
    footerTextColor = 128

    def __init__(self, data):
        super(MyFPDF, self).__init__()
        self.res = data['res'] # reseller info
        self.cust = data['customer'] # customer info


def pdfDoc():

    data = _select_offer(offerId) # data.offer data.customer
    data['res'] = db.reseller[data.offer.reseller_id] # data.res
    pdf = MyFPDF(data)
    pdf.add_page() # from here is the code for the pdf document
```

The only reason I am overriding **init**() is so I can pass in the address information for the footer. I can't pass it directly to my footer method because the method is used internally in the module. So adding an argument causes other problems.

Comment: I cannot replicate with your exact code. Can you provide more context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just worked it out. 
The problem is the unnecessary decorator @auth.requires_login() on the class declaration.